# trigger modal popup from controller

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal popup which I fill with data from my modalcontroller. After I filled it with data I would like to show it. To be able to show the modalpopup straight away when going into the page I would like to trigger it directly. Right now I have a button which does that, but how can I do it automatic in a proper way?

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" ng-init="getAllItems()">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" name="form" role="form">
                        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
                            <input type="radio" name="fundselector" ng-model="item" ng-value="item"/> {{item}} <br />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

My controller:

```
angular.module("Modal")
.controller("ModalController",
[
"$scope", "$rootScope", "$location", "ModalService", "AuthenticationService",
function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, ModalService, AuthenticationService) {

    AuthenticationService.GetCurrentWindowsUser(function(username) {
        $scope.username = username;
    });

    $scope.getAllItems = function () {
        AuthenticationService.GetCurrentWindowsUser(function (username) {
            if (username) {
                AuthenticationService.GetItems(username, function (items) {
                    $scope.items = items;
                    //Trigger modalpopup here
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: Have you tried **$('#myModal').modal('show')**

Comment: would like to use angular instead of jquery

Comment: @Vivek your answer is the best mate! thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use jquery, use angular-ui.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

You can open the modal programmatically like below, and pass your data in in the resolve. This is copy and pasted straight from their example.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Find element by angular.element and hide.

```
var popup = angular.element("#modal-default");
//for hide model
popup.modal('hide');
//for show model
popup.modal('show');
```

Comment: Love this solution. Clean and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -

$('#yourModalId').modal('show');

Answer (score 0):

To fix your example, I created a service that would open the modal and attached it to the outer controller and the modal controller.  I had to remove the "modal" class from the modal because it had a `display:none` attribute on it.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/4L9u0bdo/2/) is a fiddle that shows what I did.  However, @mgiesa's answer is better.